# How to unit test a function that does not return anything?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Is it possible to find the values of the local variables in a function by mocking?

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    a = 5000 * 10
    B().someFunction(a)
```

How do I write a unit test for this function? I have mocked `someFunction` as I do not want the testing scope to go outside the block. The only way I can test the rest of the function is by checking if the value of variable a is 50000 at the end of the function. How do I do this?

Comment: You do not unittest this code, instead you change it around so it will  be self-contained piece of application logic which is actually testable.

Comment: I assume this is just a trivial example, because your function should be rewritten `B().someFunction(50000)`

Comment: That is correct. This is an oversimplified example. My requirement is to find the values of the local variables when the last line of the function is called.

Comment: Have you find anything on this? @PradeepVairamani

Answer (score 23):

A function that does not return anything, doesn't modify anything and does not raise any error is a function that basically have no reason to be.

- If your function is supposed to assert something and raise an error,
  give it wrong information and check if it does raise the right error.
- If your function takes an object and modifies it, test if the new
  state of your object is as expected.
- If your function output
  something to the console, you can temporarily redirect the
  input/output stream and test what is written/read.

If none of the above, just delete your function and forget about it :)

Comment: The function is used to compute the values of the variables that are passed to another function. The computation of the arguments is what I want to test and it is preferable if I can test it without moving it out to a new function.

Comment: then, as suggested by elias, maybe you should consider your function as a module and write specific unit tests for whatever lies within your function.

Comment: What if, for example, a function calls a `subprocess`? What's the way to unit test that? Do we just use `subprocess.check_output(command)` and then see whether it throws  `CalledProcessError`?

Answer (score 1):

With interaction testing, you could check what value someFunction was called with. What happens inside that function, should be tested in the unit test of that function.

Answer (score -1):

Put the body of the function in a `try`/`except` block which does not return anything and return true if successful. This does not break the existing code.

ex:-

```
def fun():
    try:
        # function code
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
```